# Scope question in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new to rails and having issues with scope. I have two classes, Post and Story. each instance of Post is created with data from a form on the Story show page. One of the parameters for Post is the id of the instance of Story from which it was created. I don't know how to get this id. @story is nil even if I defined it in the controller under `def show` as `@story=Story.find(params[:id])`

Thanks!

Comment: Story.find() should raise an ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound if no record was found. Since that's not what seems to be happening you should specify in your question what it is you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on where you're creating the post, and the routing for the controllers. I'm hoping this is in a PostsController, not StoriesController - as it doesn't really belong in the latter.

And so, presuming you're using PostsController, the best approach (given every post is tied to a Story, it sounds), is to have this controller nested within stories in your `routes.rb` file:

```
resources :stories do
  resources :posts
end
```

Then, the story id (given the form is set up correctly) is available in `params[:story_id]` - and creation could look something like this:

```
story = Story.find params[:story_id]
post  = story.posts.create params[:post]
```

Working off a few assumptions here, but hopefully this is helpful.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you. I suspect the nested resources will do the trick, but I'm now getting `No route matches {:action=>"create", :controller=>"posts"}`. This points to this line of my form: `<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>`. How am I supposed to declare this now? I am indeed using the correct controller.

Comment: You'll want the form to be aware of the nesting: `<%= form_for([@story, @post]) do |f| %>`

Comment: Perfect. I figured that I had to do something similar but wasn't sure about the syntax. Thank you so much, it's all working now.